# C++ : Add a callback that will be executed when an std::future is done

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

In python you can use:

```
future.add_done_callback(f)
```

`f` will then be called with the future as it's input parameter when it has a result or if it is cancelled.

How could I do something similar in c++?

Comment: perhaps [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) that are recently added in c++20 is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::future` has `wait` method, which is blocking. Call this method inside a background thread, when `wait` returns, the future is ready, then you can call your callback with ready future as parameter:

Some code:

```
struct FutureCallback {
    std::thread th;

    template<class C>
    FutureCallback(C c, std::future<int> f) {
        th = std::thread(
            [c = std::move(c), f = std::move(f)]() mutable
            {
                f.wait();  // wait until future is ready
                c(f);      // call callback
            }
        );
    }

    ~FutureCallback() {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }
};

void callback(std::future<int>& f) {
    std::cout << "res printing in callback: " << f.get();
}

int main() {
    std::packaged_task<int()> task([](){ 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        return 10; 
    });
    std::future<int> f = task.get_future();
    FutureCallback cb(&callback,std::move(f));
    task();
```